# Is there any way to draw segues in IB while I do them programatically?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, storyboard, segue

I'm pretty new to xcode. I've been working on a project, where I have one main tab bar controller and several navigation controllers. I want to keep my following VCs in "navigation stack" so Im using following method of presenting view controllers:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
   SomeViewController *pViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ponViewController"];
    //initialize some "public variables of that controller
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pViewController animated:YES];}
```

However I reached state, when I have around 6 view controllers on my Storyboard, but they are not visually connected. My colleagues are getting confused, because when they want to see which VC connects to another, they have to look into the code...

Therefore my question... Is there any way to connect ViewControllers in InterfaceBuilder(storyboard) without creating any particular kind of segue(Modal, push, custom). Just to demonstrate connections between view controllers?

Comment: Why not use **real** push segues, either attached directly to the button or to the source view controller?  If you succeed in drawing segues that are not actually used, that will also become confusing.

Comment: To be honest I actually have one push segue done through performSegueWithIdentifier, when Im transition from tableView to detailView... But sending data through prepareForSegue method is bugged for me somehow (sometimes my app sends different attribute than it is supposed to, so far I don't know why) so I tried this different approach. I got used to it and now I want to know some reason why to use performSegueWithIdentifier :)

Comment: I think the reason is: if you're going to use storyboards, it's good to use the features they give you.  What you're currently doing is treating the storyboard as if it were a container full of nibs.  That's functional but, as you say, not something that another programmer will expect.

Comment: True, I started doing iOS programming after storyboards have been introduced. And after googling alot, pushViewController has been first thing that I discovered, so I learned to do it that way :) But from now on, I'll use performSegueWithIdentifier.. Thank you too Phillip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use segues, you don't have to use the pushViewController method to present your next view controller. You can design it all in Interface Builder and connect the view controllers with push segues. You should give each segue a unique identifier. Then in the buttonClick: method of yours, you can use

> performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)segueIdentifier sender:(id)sender

to show a view controller.

If there's anything you need to do before a view controller is pushed, you can do it in

> prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

Comment: So are there actually any differences between those two approaches? Or is performSegueWithIdentifier just better approach while using storyboards?

Comment: Since you're using a storyboard and you have all your view controllers there, there's no reason why you should use pushViewController.. You can achieve exactly the same thing using performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:. That's the meaning of having a storyboard, so that you have it all designed and managed visually.

Comment: Okay so if there aren't any other differences, you proved your point :) Accepted